# Android directory hierarchy from string

Tags: java, android, directory

I'm working on an android app that controls an MPD server.
Now I'm trying to create a music database in the app where the user can select songs to play (songs are already located on the MPD server).

Now I can pull the music list from the server with responds with a long list of info:

```
directory: USB
directory: USB/DIR1
file: USB/DIR1/song1.mp3
file: USB/DIR1/song2.mp3
file: USB/DIR1/song3.mp3
directory: USB/DIR2
file: USB/DIR2/song1.mp3
file: USB/DIR2/song2.mp3
file: USB/DIR2/song3.mp3
directory: USB/DIR2/DIR3
file: USB/DIR2/DIR3/song1.mp3
file: USB/DIR2/DIR3/song2.mp3
file: USB/DIR2/DIR3/song3.mp3
```

Now I have every song stored into a database which works etc. Every item in this database containts the song name, artist, and file path (being USB/DIR1/song1.mp3 for example).

All thats left is to make a file hierarchy from this database using folder.
I want my folder USB to have clickable maps listing the corresponding files within.

I can't yet post images, so I hope this link will work:
[example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pxrT.png)https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pxrT.png

I dont have any problems displaying items in a listview etc, i'm just curious how to make a folder hierarchy from a list of filepath strings.

All I can think of atm is making a small database where I store every folder name with the parent folder name and compare the folder URI's to a songs filepath, and display the songname in list if the songs filepath matches the folders filepath

My database extends SQLhelper so i can use SQL commands to fetch songs by name/artist/filepath

Thanks in advance!
- Meryn

Comment: if i got you correct, you may want to make it as main-sub, as main will be directories, and when directory selected the list get loaded with sub-dirs, and so on until you reach the files level, OR you can make expandable list, where dirs are main item and expanded to show files, but in case of sub-sub-dirs this might be complex for each developer and user